# Tool (javascript) to convert a XML string to JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json

What is the best javascript function/plugin/library to convert a XML string to JSON.

I found that tool : http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html, but it does not like strings starting with `0`. i.e.: `005321` get converted to `2769` (not cool :( )

My question, what is the best javascript function/plugin/library to convert a XML to JSON?

EDIT : Someone tried one that works fine?

Comment: why don't you try to write to the author about that?

Comment: @stivlo - There's a big note at the top of the page that says the author wants people to use something else "due to numerous problems reported".

Comment: That script doesn't even generate valid JSON, as it stands.

Comment: oops, right Jared, so David did you try [the one suggested](http://www.terracoder.com/index.php/xml-objectifier/xml-objectifier-introduction)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This function has worked pretty well for me:

```
xmlToJson = function(xml) {
    var obj = {};
    if (xml.nodeType == 1) {                
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { 
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }            
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Implementation:

```
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson(xmlDoc)); // xmlDoc = xml dom document
```

Comment: One handy improvement: if you change `typeof (obj[nodeName].length) == "undefined"` to `typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined"`, it stops blowing on whitespace and text elements between tags.

Comment: I've been using Object.prototype.toString.call( obj[nodeName] ) !== '[object Array]' to avoid the same problem.

Comment: @Claude: Just updated my answer with the fix suggested by jpatokal: `if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined")`

Comment: @james it returns object({}) in case of single child node could it returns like ([{}]) please?

Comment: It'd be nice to [reference source](http://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json)

Comment: One thing that really lost me on this answer is the "xml" parameter is not just a string.  It's supposed to be a Titanium.XML.DOMDocument.  Otherwise, how could you possibly call xml.hasChildNodes(), for example?  If this was mentioned somewhere, I missed it.

Comment: who has committed plagiarism? https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json

Comment: @YeneMulatu: Plagiarism? Show me where I claimed to have created this code. I claimed that it worked well for me, and probably because it was used within a project that I contributed on. This site is about helping other developers by sharing code and solutions to solve problems. Dude, get your rep up before you start lobbing BS accusations at people who have established themselves over years as trusted community members and contributors.

Answer (score 6):

Another small library for XML <=> JSON is https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use jQuery, there is:

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/

```
$.get("http://jfcoder.com/test.xml.php", function(xml){
    var json = $.xml2json(xml);
    $('pre').html(JSON.stringify(json)); // To show result in the browser
});
```

**Using:**

```
<nums>
 <num>00597</num>
 <num>0059</num>
 <num>5978</num>
 <num>5.978</num>
</nums>
```

**Outputs:**

```
{"num":["00597","0059","5978","5.978"]}
```

http://jfcoder.com/test.php

Comment: This library loses tags embedded in text: `<p>Hello <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em></p>` becomes `{"p":"Helloand"}`.