# Hierarchical XML to JSON

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I have to display a hierarchical structure and my input comes from a web service in a XML like this one:

```
<Nodes>
    <Node>
        <Data>
            <Attribute name="ID">Desktop</Attribute>
            <Attribute name="Parent">administrator</Attribute>
        </Data>
        <Relationship>
            <RelatedNodes>
                <Node>
                    <Data>
                        <Attribute name="ID">administrator</Attribute>>
                        <Attribute name="Parent">Users</Attribute>
                    </Data>
                    <Relationship>
                        <RelatedNodes>
                            <Node>
                                <Data>
                                    <Attribute name="ID">Users</Attribute>
                                    <Attribute name="Parent">C</Attribute>
                                </Data>
                                <Relationship>
                                    <RelatedNodes>
                                        <Node>
                                            <Data>
                                                <Attribute name="ID">C</Attribute>
                                                <Attribute name="Parent"/>
                                            </Data>
                                        </Node>
                                    </RelatedNodes>
                                </Relationship>
                            </Node>
                        </RelatedNodes>
                    </Relationship>
                </Node>
            </RelatedNodes>
        </Relationship>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

And to display it the UI guys are asking me to transform to a JSON like this one:

```
{
    children:[{
            "title": "C",
            "level": "1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "Users",
                    "level": "2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "title": "administrator",
                            "level": "3",
                        }, 
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "title": "Desktop",
                                "level": "4",
                            },
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
    }]
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this using XSLT or any other transformation tool?

Thanks!

Comment: Just search on SO, lot's of ways to do it, here's Javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769829/tool-javascript-to-convert-a-xml-string-to-json

Comment: Your XML is not syntactically valid (please fix it) and it's not clear how it relates to your sample JSON. What's `C` for example?

Comment: Thanks Raffian, I have found a lot of tools to do transform XML to JSON, but all these tools converts the xml literally, I mean every element of the xml is an element in JSON. The problem here is that I have a hierarchical xml structure and I don't know the deep, so I need to go to the parent that should be the deeper element in the structure and go up to the last element., but how I know the path of the parent if I don't know the depth of the structure.

Comment: It's an example with a Windows folder structure so "C" is the root folder, the example path is: C:/Users/administrator/Desktop. The JSON structure use "children" array to indicate the children of that element.

Comment: To correct the XML, please just change the line 11 with this:
<Attribute name="ID">administrator</Attribute>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a small stylesheed to give you are idea how to do deal with this probelm:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' >
    <xsl:output method='text'  encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        {
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Data[Attribute/@name ='Parent' and Attribute = '' ]/parent::Node" />
        }
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node" >
        <xsl:param name="level" select="1" />
        children:[
        {
        "title": "<xsl:value-of select="Data/Attribute[@name = 'ID']" />",
           "level": "<xsl:value-of select="$level"/>,
           <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::Node[1]">
               <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1" />
           </xsl:apply-templates>
        }
        ]

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It starts with the node which has an Attribute with name "Parent" but no value.

By the way, your xml structure is quite strange and I do not know how this should work if the structure is more complex (more nodes on the same level).

Comment: Thank you works great, I just changed the xpath in the first template to:
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Data[Attribute[@name='Parent']='' ]/parent::Node" />
It wasn't working for more complex structures.
Thank you very much!