# XML to JSON javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, xml, json

I pulled this function from another stackoverflow question(link below). I want to be able to convert the XML that I have(included as a HTML comment) to a JSON format. I thought this snippet would work but it keeps giving this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Object cat.xml has no method 'hasChildNodes'

I still trying wrap my head around javascript so I can't figure this out. I am sorry if this has been answered but I searched and can't find an answer anywhere.Here is the original question

[Tool (javascript) to convert a XML string to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769829/tool-javascript-to-convert-a-xml-string-to-json)

and here is a jsbin with what I am trying to do and with the error showing. Thank you.

http://jsbin.com/ujoPECU/1/edit

```
var xmlToJson = function (xml) {
    'use strict';
    var obj = {};
    if (xml.nodeType == 1) {
        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
            obj["@attributes"] = {};
            for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
                var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
                obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
        }
    } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) { 
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
    }            
    if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
            var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
            var nodeName = item.nodeName;
            if (typeof (obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
                obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
            } else {
                if (typeof (obj[nodeName].push) == "undefined") {
                    var old = obj[nodeName];
                    obj[nodeName] = [];
                    obj[nodeName].push(old);
                }
                obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
var jsonText = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson("cat.xml")); // xmlDoc = xml dom document
console.log(jsonText);
```

Comment: As an aside, even if it worked your `xmlToJson()` function _doesn't return JSON,_ it returns an object (which you seem to already know given you've used `JSON.stringify()` to get actual JSON from the result).

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you're trying to parse the string `"cat.xml"` as an XML document. I would suggest [reading up on XML documents in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML) but you essentially need to get the contents of your XML file, parse it into an XML document, then run it through your `xmlToJson` function (which actually returns an object).

```
var xmlString = "<a><b>C</b></a>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
var obj = xmlToJson(xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code snippet you have here looks like it comes from David Walsh's blog at https://davidwalsh.name/convert-xml-json.   The xml parameter is supposed to be a Titanium.XML.DOMDocument.  So, you can't simply pass in "cat.xml".
I am not sure what the scope of your project was, but I found the rss-to-json Node library helpful for my mobile project.

Answer (score 0):

As Browser-side javascript doesn't have permission to write (and reading XML files doesn't make sense in this case) to the client machine without a lot of security options having to be disabled, you will need to get that XML via HTTP requests to your server.

```
function XMLDoc(callback){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
      //Success
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        console.log("Response from server : "+xmlhttp.responseText);
        callback(xmlhttp.responseXML); 
      }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://yourServerAddress.com/yourfile.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

XMLDoc(function(e){
   //Now you can call your function
   var jsonText = JSON.stringify(xmlToJson(e));
   console.log("Converted JSON: "+jsonText);    
});
```